# Apache Superset configuration Issue with two different supersets on the same server

Tags: apache-superset

I have two different applications running on the same server. And for those two applications, I have different Supersets for e.g. Application1 associated with Superset1 and Application2 associated Superset2,

Whenever I am trying to configure the Superset1 db information, it is also reflected in Superset2. vice versa.

Could someone please help me how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think the problem is on the cookies. I don't know how to fix the problem but what I did was open another browser window in "private" when I want to login in a different superset. This will temporary fix the problem.